# Haskell - Why is type inferred differently in these cases?

Tags: haskell, lambda, type-inference

Why is type inferred differently when the anonymous function is bound to a name?

```
Prelude> :type (+)
(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a

Prelude> let bar (x,y) = x+y
Prelude> :type bar
bar :: Num a => (a, a) -> a

Prelude> :type \(x,y)->x+y
\(x,y)->x+y :: Num a => (a, a) -> a

Prelude> let foo =  \(x,y)->x+y
Prelude> :type foo
foo :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
```

Comment: It's the [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction).

Comment: ...which might well be the one single feature of Haskell98 that overall leads to the most confusion. Hence, _it's the **dreaded** monomorphism restriction_.

Comment: So it is just because of some language-technical idiosyncrasy, not something I am supposed to know. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily, it's worth taking a second what it is so you'll recognize when it's biting you (http://www.dannygratzer.com/2013/07/the-monomorphism-restriction.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a type defaulting in GHCi for polymorphic types.

These rules allow to use gchi as a "user friendly" "calculator" and don't use signatures.

But sure, these rules not only help, but hinder sometimes.